# mvvmcross xamarin android activity Show strange behavoir

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have two Activities like

```
[Activity(Label = "View for FirstViewModel", MainLauncher = true)]
public class FirstView : MvxActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FirstView);
    }
}

[Activity(Label = "View for SecondViewModel", MainLauncher = false)]
public class SecondView : MvxActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SecondView);
    }
}
```

and two ViewModels

```
 public class FirstViewModel 
    : MvxViewModel
{
    private string _hello = "Hello MvvmCross 1";

    public FirstViewModel()
    {

    }

    public string Hello
    { 
        get { return _hello; }
        set { _hello = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Hello); }
    }

    public ICommand Next
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>());
        }
    }
}

 public class SecondViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public SecondViewModel()
    {

    }

    private string _hello = "Hello MvvmCross 2";

    public string Hello
    {
        get { return _hello; }
        set { _hello = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Hello); }
    }

    public ICommand Back
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<FirstViewModel>());
        }
    }
```

}

I'm trying just two switch back and forth between them. the back step just does not work. Logging looks okay to me. Using the same VMs with an WPF project works just fine. So what the problem with androids activities?

Thanks in advance!

MH

Comment: What do you mean with "back step just does not work". What are you experiencing?

Comment: ICommand Back should be invoked and the first VM should be evaluated again. According to the debug log:

mvx:Diagnostic: 36,25 Showing ViewModel FirstViewModel
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 36,25 Showing ViewModel FirstViewModel

But the view does not change. SecondViewModel ist still visible.

Comment: Instead of ShowViewModel use Close(this)

Comment: Thank you! 
But what if my navigation pattern is like:
a -> b
b -> c
c -> a ? Do I always have to call Close(this) first? It disturbs the ui flow.

Both in wpf with xamarin and mvvcross and  in android studio this scenario works well.